# How to create template file for biagrams in crf++

Tags: crf++

I have train file in following format. 
 
 word(column0), its corresponding biagram(column 1-21) and word(column 22).

For example  
दुव्र्यवहार     दु     ुव     व्     ्र     र्     ्य     यव     वह     हा     ार     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     -     - व्यवहार
I have to create a template such that on the basis of biagram, model can predict the word(word at last column)

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you a need 22 feature templates ( for column 0 - 21 ) in your template file and it should work.

You can a look at youtu.be/GJHeTvDkIaE to get a better understanding about template file.